# C# and Mono to access Azure from Raspberri Pi?

Tags: c#, azure, mono, raspberry-pi, azure-blob-storage

Im trying to download blobs from Azure using my Respberry Pi. The code is solid, it works fine on my desktop. It appears that mono does not have azure assemblies capability, but I read that you can use mono to access azure so I'm wondering if Im making a mistake.

My code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Configuration;

namespace CPGetFamilyPhotos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureImagesConnection"].ConnectionString);
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Retrieve a reference to a container.
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("newAdverts").ListBlobs();
            // Retrieve filenames from container List
            var urls = new List<string>();
            int fileName = 1;

            foreach (var blob in container)
            {
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"\home\pi\Pictures\" + fileName + ".jpg"))
                {
                    var blobReference = blobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(blob.Uri);
                    blobReference.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
                    fileName++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have built the program for release and copied entire release folder across to the Pi.
I have run `mozroots –import –ask-remove  --machine`

Contents of my folder on the Pi:
[image]

Image of the error (There is a slight overlap in the images).
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: the image includes just text, please include the text rather than an image, because this way it will be searchable by google/stackoverflow and indexed properly

Comment: Apologies,  I couldn't copy the text from the remote terminal onto my desktop. That would have been my preference but the screen cap was the only option.

Answer (score 1):

As from error, you will need to make sure all the dependence that your code require are there. In this case it is `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll`

> "I have built the file and copied my .exe across to the Pi"

You will need to copy .exe and all the dll that required (do a release build and look at your bin folder)

Comment: I tried that @Xiaomin Wu but still no success. I have updated my question to reflect the new error. I appreciate your help, I'm completely lost with this.

Comment: @DMur seems like your first issue resolved. and now you are hitting authentication issue. Try what Gusman suggest,  if not work, try to not use HTTPS as to proof whether your app will work, try to separate the issue.

Comment: Hi @Xiaomin Wu. When I debug my app from my desktop it works perfectly. Then I create the release build and copy it to the raspberrypi to run using mono and it doesnt work. "try to not use HTTPS as to proof whether your app will work" - Can you explain what you mean by this please?

Comment: Regarding to "HTTPS", i think Azure Storage library by default is using HTTPS to communicate with storage account. so i guess if you can find a way to not use HTTPS, you might be able to work-around the issue for now, and see if there is other blocker.

Comment: do you develop on mono on linux? if not try to setup an linux enviroment and develop on mono to see if your app still work

Comment: I have switched to Win IOT Core instead, hopefully it will work a bit smoother with azure. Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: i see. yeah it will be better if your dev environment is similar to your deployment environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are the root certificates. If you look at the exception it clearly says it cannot identify the TLS connection certificate.

First of all try the solutions exposed here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/

The mozroots solution usually works the best, just execute it and all the certificates will be updated.

If that does not solve your problem you can always hook to the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback event and accept the certificate by yourself.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that when I get back tonight.

Comment: No joy @Gusman. How do I "hook to the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback event and accept the certificate by yourself."? At this point I dont think this works, so my next option is dump everything I've done in rasbian and start again with Win IOT Core. (Or learn python!)

Comment: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback is just an event, hook to any other normal event and return true, it will accept the certificate even if it can't be verified